# Maximun price of an item using index formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find maximum price of an item from the list of items from column B and minimum price of the item from column C.

I get desired reults by using an array formula with `MIN`and `MAX` functions.However I prefer non array formula. Array Forumals in F2 and G2 respectively are:

```
 =MIN(IF(A$2:A$15=E2,C$2:C$15,""))

 =MAX(IF(A$2:A$15=E2,B$2:B$15,""))
```

I am able to get desired results using non-array function for minimum value using `Index` and `MIN` functions. But the effort to get the maximum value does not produce desired results. Formula for Minimum Value and Maximum Values in `H2` and `I2` are mentioned blow.

```
 =MIN(INDEX((C$2:C$15)+(A$2:A$15<>E2)*1E+99, , ))

 =MAX(INDEX((B$2:B$15)+(A$2:A$15<>E2)*1E+99, , ))
```

Request help in suitable modification in in the formula `=MAX(INDEX((B$2:B$15)+(A$2:A$15<>E2)*1E+99, , ))` to get maximum value of an item from Column B which presently gives 1E99 as result.

My data and corresponding results are mentioned below.

```
A       B       C          E         F       G          H        I
Prod_ID High_Pr Low_Pr      Prod_ID Min_Pr1  Max_Pr1    Min_Pr2  Max_Pr2
    A1  1050    1050        A1      1038     1058       1038    1E99
    A1  1058    1058        A2      2110     2122       2110    
    A1  1048.5  1048.5      A3      1958     1962       1958    
    A1  1045    1045                        
    A1  1040    1040                        
    A1  1038    1038                        
    A1  1040.99 1039                        
    A2  2122    2115.01                     
    A2  2112    2112                        
    A2  2114.5  2110                        
    A2  2110    2110                        
    A3  1962    1958.1                      
    A3  1960    1958.1                      
    A3  1958    1958
```

**EDIT**

I defined named ranges for `A2:A15` as `Prod_ID` and for range `B2:B15` as `High_Pr`. Then I used `AGGREGATE` Function in `I2` as mentioned below and copied it further down. This gives the desired results . I still look forward for a better approach.

```
  =AGGREGATE(14,6,High_Pr*(Prod_ID=E2),ROW(E2)-ROW(E1))
```

Snapshot of results obtained appended below.

[image: aggregate_approach]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a pivot table is the answer to what you're looking for.  I recommend watching this and seeing if it assists you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO_2nxRcpZg

Additionally, if you do not object to addins, Excel Power Query would do this for you as well. But I think all you really need is a pivot table, the most undervalued feature of Excel and all spreadsheets. :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your interest in this question. I am preferring formula as this is a small part of a large formula based project. I am quite familar with pivot tables , However I feel sorry that I should have mentioned it in my question. I am accepting your answer as this is one of the correct answers.